# Adding a form for storing hash type mongoid column in rails using simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a model Test using mongoid in rails, where I have a column as a type Hash. The structure is as follows:

```
_id: 123456asasa, 
observations: {:table=>
[{
     :view=>"abc.com",
     :goals=>"Test,Event", 
     :num_conversions=>0, 
     :remarks=>"Ok"
 }, 
 {
        :view=>"www.abc.com",
        :goals=>"Test,Event,Duration", 
        :num_conversions=>10, 
        :remarks=>"Test"
    }], 
    :comment=>"This is a test sample"
}
```

Now I want to write a form for this using simpleform gem, observations can have multiple records of table.

Please suggest me how to proceed in this.

Answer (score 0):

You need two different models, [see this doc to embed the second one into the observations model](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many). I'm not using simpleform but mongoid supports scaffolding so you can just generate the basic skeleton both of your models and forms with "rails g scaffold table view:String goals:String num_conversions:Integer" ... etc.